# What values will be assigned to variables.[Need to Understand the program Logic]

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I am a beginner in Verilog.I need to understand the logic of a testcase but I am having difficulty because of the logic of these variables.

Are these 'define F and G of integer types.I read that parameter are constants.

```
    'define F 32
    'define G 0

    module M(...);

    parameter  pMaxPacketsSize =1024;
    localparam pTotalBits=3*'G;
    localparam pForcePktSize=(pMaxPacketsSize-'F);
    localparam pLastPacketSize =((pTotalBits-1)%(pForcePktSize))+1;
    localparam pNumTransactions=((pTotalBits-1)/(pForcePktSize))+1;
    localparam pPortSize=(pNumTransactions>1)?pMaxPacketsSize:((((pTotalBits-1)/32)+1)*32)+'F;
```

As G is defined to be 0,
what will be the value of ForcePacketsize.I attempted binary subtraction and arrived at 128(7 bits)[Is this Correct?].[0-32].Are all these operations needs to be performed in binary arithmetic.I want to know the value of these parameters(pForcePktSize,pLastPacketSize,PNumTransactions).

One more statement I want to understand is this:

```
wire[pPortSize-1:0]D;
wire[pNumTransactions-1:0] t;
assign t=1'b1<<D[14:0];
```

I know it is of type :[size][radix][value] means 1 in binary then left shifting,but how this is being assigned to array(will t be 100000000000000   14 zeroes and then 1)

I tried to run online on some IDE's but get error that I give up.

Answer (score 0):

`` `define `` in verilog is the same thing as `#define` in `c`. It defines a text macro. `` `G `` and `` `F `` instantiate macros and get replaced by their context in the program before parsing.

So, in your case

```
localparam pTotalBits=3*'G;
localparam pForcePktSize=(pMaxPacketsSize-'F);
```

will be replaced with

```
localparam pTotalBits=3*0;
localparam pForcePktSize=(pMaxPacketsSize-32);
```

The replacement is textual and instantiations of the macros just got replaced with their definitions. There is **no** type associated with macro definition.

Comment: so what value will be stored in pLastPacketSize?does binary modulo take place

Comment: Sorry, got extra back tick in the substitution, fixed. `pTotalBits` will be `0`.  `pLastPacketSize` will  be `1024 - 32 = 992`